# Solr generic search, how to remove some fields from the search?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'd like to do a simple search in Solr like q=1234. I know it will look for the queryString in every field configured in the schema.xml BUT, I'd like, on runtime, it to NOT search in certain fields.

Is that possible with Solr?

I don't want to do filter queries. I want to search in every fields configured but not some, depending, for instance, on the user rights.

Thanks a lot for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong - `q=1234` will *not* search every field. The default schema has a field named `_text_` and a `copyField` rule that copies the content of all fields into that field - and then the `_text_` field is searched by default.

That means that as long as you actually specify which fields you want to search, you get the behaviour you want. With the (e)dismax handlers, you do this by setting `qf=field1 field2 field3` with the field names you want to search.

You should also remove the `copyField` instruction and the `_text_` field unless you're planning on using that functionality.

Comment: Hi Mats, thanks for the hint, I'll look closer that way, thanks!